# Passing variable parameter to db.Query results in illegal variable name: ASP/HTML/WebMatrix

Tags: html, asp.net, oracle, parameters, webmatrix

Thank you for taking the time to view my post.
I have provided links of what I have read to try and resolve this problem as well as the learning material I have used.

The following is the code I am having an issue with. I have tried varied permutations of this code to get it to work and I believe the main problem lies within my variable setting. I am querying an external Oracle database.

```
    @{
    var db = Database.Open("DBNAME");
    var searchterm = "";
    var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = @0";
    if (!Request.QueryString["searchterm"].IsEmpty()){
        searchterm = Request.QueryString["searchterm"];
                                                      }
  var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery);
  var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);  



}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Movies</title>

    </head>
    <body>
            <form method ="get">
                <label for="searchterm">Please enter you UNIQUEVALUE</label>
                <input type="text" name="searchterm" value="@Request.QueryString["searchterm"]" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search UNIQUEVALUE" />

            </form>
        <div>
                    @grid.GetHtml()
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following will work about the way I want it to

```
@{
 var db = Database.Open("DBNAME");
        var searchterm = "";
        var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = 'A00000000'";
        if (!Request.QueryString["searchterm"].IsEmpty()){
            searchterm = Request.QueryString["searchterm"];
                                                        }
      var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery);
      var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData); 

}
```

But when I change it to the following it breaks with the this error:

```
@{
        var db = Database.Open("DBNAME");
        var searchterm = "";
        var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = @0";
        if (!Request.QueryString["searchterm"].IsEmpty()){
            searchterm = Request.QueryString["searchterm"];
                                                        }
      var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery,searchterm);
      var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);  


}
```

System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

```
Line 7:              searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = @0";                                            
Line 8:                                                          }
***Line 9:        var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery,searchterm);***
Line 10:       var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);
```

Modified the line to look like below. Even trying to pass a static value in a parameter field is not working out for me.

```
var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery,"A00000000");
```

I have verified this query returns data using Webmatrix when I hard code the query.

```
var searchQuery= "SELECT * FROM DATABASENAME.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUE ID = 'A00000000'"
 var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery);
```

I have tried several different ways of quoting the @0, and adding single quotes to search term after the value has been set. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Leaning/Research/Articles Read:

### Searches done on Stack Overflow:

System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
HTML ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number\
ASP illegal variable name/number
ASP DB.Query()

### Searches done on Google:

Db.Query Parameters

### Articles read on Stack overflow:

[System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107183/system-data-oracleclient-oracleexception-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-numbe) (different syntax/language)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398488/adding-parameters-to-db-query-using-webmatrix

[Constructing a good search query using system.data.oracleclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412023/constructing-a-good-search-query-using-system-data-oracleclient)

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361667/win32exception-0x80004005-the-wait-operation-timed-out)

[Connecting html pages + Razor to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655912/connecting-html-pages-razor-to-database)

[Passing parameters to db.query with arangojs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650706/passing-parameters-to-db-query-with-arangojs)

### Articles read on google:

[What is the Equivalent of ObjectQuery.Parameters in DbQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700983/what-is-the-equivalent-of-objectquery-parameters-in-dbquery)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91c7fb6d-d1b8-4a7f-aec9-16336dbd619b/access-to-dbquery-parameters-for-logging?forum=adodotnetentityframework

### Learning Material used to get this far:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data (read through, and actively coded with this tutorial.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you tried several ways to quote the parameter. However, this is Oracle and they use a :0 for the parameterization. Did you try

```
var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = ':0'";
```

The :0 parameter just drops the passed string into the sql string.

[Oracle parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048910/oraclecommand-sql-parameters-binding)

Comment: Hi Knox! 

Thank you for reviewing my question. I have tried that method. 

        var searchterm = "A00000000";
        var searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = '@0'";
var selectedData = db.Query(searchQuery,searchterm);

I have also tried the following:

var searchTerm= "''A00000000'";
var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = '@0'";

And this as well:

var searchTerm= "'";
var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE.DATABASETABLE WHERE UNIQUEID = '@0'";
searchTerm = "'" + Request.QueryString[searchterm"]; + "'"

Comment: most of the examples are for SQL Server.  Oracle uses a colon instead of the at sign for parameterization.   You might not need the single quotes, so give that a try too.

Comment: Knox! YOU'RE MY HERO. Changing the positional parameter to :0 allowed the query to go through. Would you be able to put me in the right direction for the documentation you used? I would like to reference it in the future.

Comment: Since you had pointed out that the one difference was oracle, and i had a difference experience with a different database where the parameterization didn't work, I looked at stack overflow for parameters and Oracle.  The link is at the bottom of my updated answer.